# Как бороться с любителями "закрыть вопрос"?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов

Приветствую.

Задаю вопрос. Через некоторое время суток залетают "озабоченные" и голосуют за "закрытие вопроса". Причем, без диалога, без комментов - просто так. Ну я понимаю, если вопрос "размытый", "не однозначный", да - нужно чего-то делать. Но если ты не понимаешь просто сути вопроса, и даже спросить не можешь по теме - закрывать зачем?

[Простой пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/606692/%D0%90%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D1%8D%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-hdd-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) - есть конкретный вопрос. Ни обсуждения, ни одного коммента, но замечаю "кому-то" вопрос не по душе ... "просто так". [Развожу руками] и сказать то и нечего.

Comment: Мне нравится ваш вопрос, но бы его на вашем месте отредактировал, чтобы он был похож на вопрос, а не на оскорбительную жалобу. По сути, вопрос про несогласие с закрытием вопроса в случае, когда нет соответствующих привилегий на переоткрытие, видится мне очень толковым.

Comment: Особенно сильно смущает слово "озабоченные". Здесь не принято оскорблять других участников, даже если вы с ними в чём-то кардинально не согласны.

Comment: В слове "озабоченные" - оскорблений нет, если только разве что действительно есть чему оскорбляться. Совсем недавно я видел какой-то рейтинговый список отдельных участников (любителей позакрывать), не могу найти сейчас, и не помню как на него вышел. Так у некоторых число вопросов, в которых они принимали участие в закрытии - значительно больше, чем у многих на порядки. Боюсь соврать - а возможно и больше собственных полезных ответов. Не нужно обижаться на правду.

Comment: Вы просто не понимаете, что здесь есть правила. И вопрос закрывается *в соответствии* с правилами (а не "от балды"). И следить за соблюдением правил тоже очень важно, иначе будет хаос.

Comment: Я вас сильно поддерживаю в том, что есть очень хорошие и полезные вопросы, и я бы очень не хотел, чтобы их закрывали с любыми формулировками ("слишком общий", "невозможно дать объективный ответ" и т.д.). На мой взгляд, даже если ответы будут размером в  статьи, вопросы не перестанут быть полезными и не перестанут нуждаться в новых ответах. Но ваши формулировки явно не предрасполагают относится к вам дружественно и поддерживать вас.

Answer (score 13):

Для начала - попробуйте перестать оскорблять других участников. Ваш [удаленный] коммент под вопросом - на грани бана.

Не знаю почему вы решили что ваш вопрос решили закрыть "просто так" или потому что кто-то "не понимает суть вопроса".

Насколько я вижу - ваш вопрос закрывают с причиной "слишком общий".

> В текущем виде на ваш вопрос невозможно дать лаконичный ответ.

Вы просите подробного описания алгоритмов кэширования. При этом явно требуете не просто обзорного ответа (размером "всего лишь" в среднюю статью), а огромного,  подробного и длинного описания. Да еще и с двумя "под-вопросами".

А в качестве альтернативы - просите накидать вам ссылок.

Что и вызывает у многих участников желание ткнуть в кнопку "закрыть".

Comment: Такие участники вряд ли достигнут существенных успехов в программировании.

Comment: @avp пусть это будет их проблемой

Comment: @PashaPash, когда среди "закрывающих" тему, напомню, про аппаратные алгоритмы - вижу специалиста по разметке html, хочется спросить "ты то тут что забыл?".

Comment: @Majestio как вы определяете в чем человек специалист, а в чем нет? Наличие большинства голосов в какой-то метке еще не значит, что он в других областях профан

Comment: Посещение его сайта, знакомство с областью его интересов.

Answer (score 7):

*Собственно, мой голос за закрытие этого вопроса прилетел первым, так что есть все основания считать меня зачинщиком "торжества".*

---

У вас прямо из вопроса следует, что вы ожидаете ответ огромного объёма: вам уже не нужны обзорные статьи по теме (каждая из которых размером наверняка больше типичного ответа SO), нужно ли говорить, что более детальное описание займёт больший объем и потребует больше усилий для написания.

Ситуация усугубляется тем, что правят бал в этой области проприетарные прошивки,  информация о деталях работы которых может быть запатентована или составлять коммерческую или иную (см. комментарий о закладках АНБ/NSA) тайну, а потому информация в ответах (которых не будет, чуть ниже объясню) будет труднопроверяемой (а гипотетически, её публикация может быть даже незаконной). Всё-таки контроллеры дисков это предмет для гордости каждого производителя НЖМД.

В общем, вопрос закрыт **не потому, что он плохой, а потому что на него в текущем виде просто никто не будет отвечать и вам стоит сузить его**, чтобы был хоть малейший шанс на хороший ответ. В частности, даже ваши подвопросы в конце закрытого уже затрагивают достаточно крупные темы, чтобы быть отдельными вопросами в формате SO. И оставлять комментарий смысла я не видел, т. к. в причине более-менее сказано, что не так и что с этим делать.

---

Ах да, я забыл ответить на, собственно, вопрос: **как бороться с закрывашками?** Ответ: **никак, это заведомо неравный бой, да и это не в ваших интересах**. Можете попросить рекомендации в комментариях или в чате, ну или на Мете, как сейчас, если первые два способа не возымели эффекта.

*Хотя я знаю один чит: запустить конкурс (когда вопрос ещё **не** закрыт). Он не даст закрыть вопрос, пока идёт (неделю, или сколько там, ни разу ещё не пробовал). Но это умножит реакцию сообщества в разы, а на злостный оффтопик может даже призвать модератора, который может конкурс отменить. Будьте готовы к непредвиденным последствиям. Но как способ "поручиться своим именем в спорной ситуации" он работает.*

Comment: "Как бороться со здравым смыслом"

Comment: IMHO не очень красиво столь самоуверенно утверждать, что *никто тут ...*. После пары ссылок  в моих комментариях [к этому вопросу](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/606692) и некоторого размышления автор и сам мог бы написать ответ (а может кто еще захочет) о принципах пресловутой дисковой буферизации.

Comment: Что же касается борьбы... Вы уверены, что обиженные в самом деле не смогут объединится и устроить тут ... (мягко говоря, саботаж)

Comment: @avp я говорю о собственном мотиве, как человек, закрытие инициировавший. Некрасиво? Что поделать. Да, автор конечно может написать ответ на совсем другой вопрос под своим, а на текущий вопрос просто обзор принципов не отвечает, так написано в самом вопросе. Так что вопрос менять в любом случае. Смогут ли обидчики скоординироваться и устроить саботаж? Смогут. Но существенного ущерба не нанесут, да и заметный ущерб лишь в том случае, если их будет достаточно много, но ущерб может быть достаточно быстро ликвидирован, все ходы о "ценном имуществе"  (контенте) записываются.

Comment: @avp, увы - не могу написать до сих пор. Ссылки на материал действительно хорошие, многие нюансы раскрывают. Но ответа там нет. Пока пришла в голову типа догадка - а что если сгрузить с сайта-производителя очередной апдейт фирмваре и задизассемблить его. Но, увы, надежды крайне мало, даже если точно знать тип используемого проца. Нужна производственная документация. Любая. Просто для осознания примера "одного-из". Нет в сети, вернее мне в сети найти не удалось.

Comment: @Majestio, вот в http://spritesmods.com/?art=hddhack из комментария jfs хакер как раз исследует содержимое дискового кэша. А в чем у вас конкретно затык с пониманием? Алгорим кэширования? Ну, детали у всех, наверное, разные. Суть одна, пока ищем заданный сектор, все читаем и сохраняем в кэше и используем при след. запросе.

Comment: Господа, возможно, вам стоит сделать для этого обсуждения отдельный чат. Его точно не закроют :)

Comment: @avp, "с пониманием"? Сколько и чего читается вперед (упреждающих секторов, треков, упреждающих треков)? Пока только это.

Comment: @D-side, чет не вижу кнопки "добавить в чат", наверное еще мало наговорили?

Comment: @Majestio дожидаться кнопки необязательно, можно просто зайти на сайт чатов SE и сделать там комнату, для этого надо 100 репы всего иметь.

Comment: Ну если разговор "не завянет" можно и сделать.

Comment: @Majestio, я сделал http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51130/hdd, только как подключаться туда спросите кого-нибудь еще.

Answer (score 5):

> Как бороться с любителями “закрыть вопрос”?

*Не хочу быть Капитаном, но* - **"Задавать хорошие вопросы!"**

Почитайте справку, о том на [на какие темы здесь можно задавать вопросы?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

А также, вот этот сборник статей на тему [как задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Может лучше попытаться дать хороший ответ? Ну, конечно, это не относится к *любому* вопросу, но к [вопросу ТС](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/606692/232) из-за которого возникло это обсуждение, уж точно применимо (например, я с удовольствием покопался в гугле несколько часов, разбираясь в сути дела).

Comment: @avp, спасибо за адекватный ответ и тут, и по тематике. За время бана узнал много нового о данном ресурсе и о части тутошних обитателей. К примеру, прочел это - https://habrahabr.ru/post/311322/ ... иллюзий больше нет.

Comment: @Majestio вы лучше комментарии там почитайте

Comment: Я ознакомился с разными мнениями, было интересно.